# Can you just put drywall up in a basement without providing electrical outlets?

Tags: walls, receptacle, partition

I would like to add 2 by 4 framing and drywall in the basement to insulate and partition into a workout area and a closet. I plan to only use overhead lighting and not put in any electrical outlets on the framed drywall. Instead, electrical boxes will be mounted externally to provide electricity to exercise equipment where needed. The area will be carpeted. 
Question is whether it is necessary to install builtin electrical outlets to drywall partitions in a basement (like every 10' or something like that).

Comment: Are you getting a permit?  Are you building the room according local building codes? Does the basement have an emergency rescue window/door?

Comment: Yes will get permit etc. if needed.  Want to get the scope of work figured out first.  I don't want to deal with new or changes in wiring, definitely not emergency window/door at this time. Just frame, drywall, and insulated. I was hoping that will not be considered as finished basement, therefore not have to meet all the associated codes.

Comment: If it's a habitable room (which it will be), you'll need to meet all codes including emergency escape and rescue openings. That is, if you get a permit.  If you don't get a permit, you can do whatever you want (as long as you're willing to accept any and all consequences).

Comment: I guess, It is then what it is.  Well alternatively, just insulate the wall with foam panels (without drywall). Would that be treated the same as habitable room ? I don't want to violate code in case I sell the house in the future.

Comment: Throw up insulation on the walls, and put down some of those [interlocking foam pads](https://www.amazon.com/We-Sell-Mats-Interlocking-Anti-Fatigue/dp/B00DXXKG9Q) on the floor.  Then you're not building a room, so no need for permits or codes. Or build a room, use the room, and if need be, remove the room before you sell. Just don't let anybody burn to death in the room, or you might be held liable.

Answer (score 3):

To meet electrical code you need outlets at certain minimum spacings, at least one on each wall that's more than 2 feet long, no more than 12 feet apart, etc - but code does not give a rat's patootie if they are IN the wall or surface-mount.

Your future resale may be helped by putting them in the wall, however - but it's not code, just typical buyer preference against seeing surface mount devices in "finished" spaces.

"*Only running outlets where you need them*" generally does **not** meet code, unless you need them in enough places that you happen to cover the code-minimum spacing requirements.

Comment: What if I just put up drywall and insulate the wall and leave the ceiling and floor bare ?  I just want a warm area for exercise or group meeting..

Comment: ...and then you'll be running extension cords all over to power things, which is precisely what that aspect of the code is trying to prevent. One more reminder - it's published by the National **Fire Prevention** Association, not the IBEW. The fire you don't prevent may be your own.

Comment: The insurance claim that gets denied may be your own.